# ngMessage in link $transclude function (Controller 'ngMessages' can't be found)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created a directive for deduplicating form error messages code:

```
angular.module('errorMessages', ['ngMessages'])
.directive('meErrorMessages', function() {
        return {
            templateUrl: '/app/common/errorMessages/errorMessages.html',
            transclude: true,

            scope : {
                formName: '=',
                inputName: '='
            },
            link: function ($scope, $element, $attrs, $ctrl, $transclude) {
                $transclude(function(
                    angular.forEach(clone, function(cloneElement) {
                        cloneElement.class = 'errorBox';
                    })
                })
            }
        }
    });
```

with template HTML:

```
<div ng-show="inputName.$touched || formName.$submitted" ng-messages="inputName.$error">
    <ng-transclude></ng-transclude>
</div>
```

However, when using the template function in the HTML:

```
<input id="name" name="name" type="text" ng-model="user.name" required />
    <me-error-messages form-name="registrationForm"
                       input-name="registrationForm.name">
        <div ng-message="required">Required</div>
    </me-error-messages>
```

I get

```
Error: [$compile:ctreq] Controller 'ngMessages', required by directive 'ngMessage', can't be found!
```

When I remove the `link` function the transcluded content is displayed and hidden correctly. What's wrong with the `$transclude` function and how can I modify the DOM of the transcluded content?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think you're supposed to use *both* `ngTransclude` and `$transclude`, just one or the other.

Comment: you're right. But removing it didn't help.